# Xwiki: Failed to extract Entity Resource Reference from URL [https://my.domain.com/bin/view/Main/]

Tags: tomcat, nginx, xwiki

when i deploy xwiki and visit the page i get the following stacktrace. i can't figure out whats wrong.

I am trying to connect to a MySQL Database (actually it's mariadb).

i should probably mention that my tomcat server is behind an nginx server which acts as a reverse proxy. this is also configured in the `server.xml`

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 11007 in 0: Failed to extract Entity Resource Reference from URL [https://my.domain.com/bin/view/Main/]
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:520)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:427)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)
    org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:127)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:136)
root cause

com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 11007 in 0: Failed to extract Entity Resource Reference from URL [https://my.domain.com/bin/view/Main/]
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeResourceFromURL(XWiki.java:926)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:793)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:255)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:210)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)
    org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:127)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:136)
root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to locate wiki descriptor for alias [my.domain.com]
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.getWikiDescriptorByAlias(AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.java:80)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.resolveDomainBasedWikiReference(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.extract(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.extractWikiReference(BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:92)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:65)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:43)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:93)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:48)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeResourceFromURL(XWiki.java:922)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:793)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:255)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:210)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)
    org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:127)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:136)
root cause

org.xwiki.wiki.manager.WikiManagerException: Failed to locate XWiki.XWikiServerClass document for wiki alias [my.domain.com]
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.document.DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.findXWikiServerClassDocumentReference(DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.java:128)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.document.DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.findXWikiServerClassDocument(DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.java:140)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.DefaultWikiDescriptorManager.getByAlias(DefaultWikiDescriptorManager.java:146)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.getWikiDescriptorByAlias(AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.java:78)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.resolveDomainBasedWikiReference(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.extract(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.extractWikiReference(BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:92)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:65)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:43)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:93)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:48)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeResourceFromURL(XWiki.java:922)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:793)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:255)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:210)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)
    org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:127)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:136)
root cause

org.xwiki.query.QueryException: Exception while translating [where doc.object(XWiki.XWikiServerClass).server = :wikiAlias and doc.name like 'XWikiServer%'] XWQL query to the [hql] language. Query statement = [where doc.object(XWiki.XWikiServerClass).server = :wikiAlias and doc.name like 'XWikiServer%']
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.XWQLQueryExecutor.execute(XWQLQueryExecutor.java:130)
    org.xwiki.query.internal.DefaultQueryExecutorManager.execute(DefaultQueryExecutorManager.java:72)
    org.xwiki.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:287)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.document.DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.findXWikiServerClassDocumentReference(DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.java:121)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.document.DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.findXWikiServerClassDocument(DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.java:140)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.DefaultWikiDescriptorManager.getByAlias(DefaultWikiDescriptorManager.java:146)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.getWikiDescriptorByAlias(AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.java:78)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.resolveDomainBasedWikiReference(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.extract(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.extractWikiReference(BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:92)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:65)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:43)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:93)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:48)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeResourceFromURL(XWiki.java:922)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:793)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:255)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:210)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)
    org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:127)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:136)
root cause

com.xpn.xwiki.XWikiException: Error number 3202 in 3: Exception while reading document [xwiki:XWiki.XWikiServerClass]
    com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiHibernateStore.java:996)
    com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiCacheStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiCacheStore.java:280)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getDocument(XWiki.java:1811)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getDocument(XWiki.java:1864)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXClass(XWiki.java:6065)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getClass(XWiki.java:6078)
    com.xpn.xwiki.doc.DefaultDocumentAccessBridge.isPropertyCustomMapped(DefaultDocumentAccessBridge.java:497)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.QueryContext$PropertyInfo.isCustomMapped(QueryContext.java:153)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.QueryContext$ObjectInfo.isCustomMapped(QueryContext.java:122)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.hql.ObjectPrinter.print(ObjectPrinter.java:37)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.hql.Printer.print(Printer.java:70)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.hql.XWQLtoHQLTranslator.translate(XWQLtoHQLTranslator.java:61)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.XWQLQueryExecutor.execute(XWQLQueryExecutor.java:97)
    org.xwiki.query.internal.DefaultQueryExecutorManager.execute(DefaultQueryExecutorManager.java:72)
    org.xwiki.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:287)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.document.DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.findXWikiServerClassDocumentReference(DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.java:121)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.document.DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.findXWikiServerClassDocument(DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.java:140)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.DefaultWikiDescriptorManager.getByAlias(DefaultWikiDescriptorManager.java:146)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.getWikiDescriptorByAlias(AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.java:78)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.resolveDomainBasedWikiReference(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.extract(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.extractWikiReference(BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:92)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:65)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:43)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:93)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:48)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeResourceFromURL(XWiki.java:922)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:793)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:255)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:210)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)
    org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:127)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:136)
root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: listGroupsForUserInOtherWiki, getAllUsers, getWatchlistJobDocuments, getAllDocuments, getAllPublicDocuments, getSpaceDocsName, getAllSpaceDocuments, listGroupsForUser, getWikiMacroDocuments, getSpaces
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:426)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
    com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateBaseStore.initHibernate(XWikiHibernateBaseStore.java:259)
    com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateBaseStore.checkHibernate(XWikiHibernateBaseStore.java:703)
    com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiHibernateStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiHibernateStore.java:861)
    com.xpn.xwiki.store.XWikiCacheStore.loadXWikiDoc(XWikiCacheStore.java:280)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getDocument(XWiki.java:1811)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getDocument(XWiki.java:1864)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXClass(XWiki.java:6065)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getClass(XWiki.java:6078)
    com.xpn.xwiki.doc.DefaultDocumentAccessBridge.isPropertyCustomMapped(DefaultDocumentAccessBridge.java:497)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.QueryContext$PropertyInfo.isCustomMapped(QueryContext.java:153)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.QueryContext$ObjectInfo.isCustomMapped(QueryContext.java:122)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.hql.ObjectPrinter.print(ObjectPrinter.java:37)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.hql.Printer.print(Printer.java:70)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.hql.XWQLtoHQLTranslator.translate(XWQLtoHQLTranslator.java:61)
    org.xwiki.query.xwql.internal.XWQLQueryExecutor.execute(XWQLQueryExecutor.java:97)
    org.xwiki.query.internal.DefaultQueryExecutorManager.execute(DefaultQueryExecutorManager.java:72)
    org.xwiki.query.internal.DefaultQuery.execute(DefaultQuery.java:287)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.document.DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.findXWikiServerClassDocumentReference(DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.java:121)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.document.DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.findXWikiServerClassDocument(DefaultWikiDescriptorDocumentHelper.java:140)
    org.xwiki.wiki.internal.descriptor.DefaultWikiDescriptorManager.getByAlias(DefaultWikiDescriptorManager.java:146)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.getWikiDescriptorByAlias(AbstractWikiReferenceExtractor.java:78)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.resolveDomainBasedWikiReference(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.extract(DomainWikiReferenceExtractor.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.extractWikiReference(BinEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:92)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.entity.AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(AbstractEntityResourceReferenceResolver.java:51)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:61)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.GenericResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(GenericResourceReferenceResolver.java:47)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:65)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.standard.StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(StandardExtendedURLResourceReferenceResolver.java:43)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:93)
    org.xwiki.url.internal.DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.resolve(DefaultResourceReferenceResolver.java:48)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.initializeResourceFromURL(XWiki.java:922)
    com.xpn.xwiki.XWiki.getXWiki(XWiki.java:793)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:255)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.XWikiAction.execute(XWikiAction.java:210)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    com.xpn.xwiki.web.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:112)
    org.xwiki.wysiwyg.server.filter.ConversionFilter.doFilter(ConversionFilter.java:127)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetHTTPHeaderFilter.doFilter(SetHTTPHeaderFilter.java:63)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SavedRequestRestorerFilter.doFilter(SavedRequestRestorerFilter.java:208)
    org.xwiki.container.servlet.filters.internal.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:111)
    org.xwiki.resource.servlet.RoutingFilter.doFilter(RoutingFilter.java:136)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.39 logs.
```

Comment: Is there anything in the tomcat log files? Usually if something with connecting to the DB goes wrong, the actual error can be found there, and the web server only shows consequential errors

Comment: it prints a stacktrace for ever named query and says `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: XWikiDocument is not mapped [
    select distinct doc.space from XWikiDocument doc order by doc.space asc
  ]
`

Comment: If you are using `xwiki-9.6.war1, the 1WEB-INF\hibernate.cfg.xml` file is not well-formed. There is a missing comment-closing tag at the `HSQLDB configuration` section. Take me hours to solve the issue, and this thread helped me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the failure. i had to uncomment these line in the hibernate configuration.

```
<mapping resource="xwiki.hbm.xml"/> 
<mapping resource="feeds.hbm.xml"/> 
<mapping resource="activitystream.hbm.xml"/> 
<mapping resource="instance.hbm.xml"/>
<mapping resource="mailsender.hbm.xml"/>
```

Comment: would be helpful to list the location of this hibernate config. Someone preceding me had built this and I know nothing about it's set up.

Comment: in my case, there are already uncommented. I use the docker image xwiki:lts-mysql-tomcat  with image mysql:5.7. Issue still regularly appears

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for a similar issue of mine and wanted to post this in case it helps anyone. I had to reboot the Apache Service within the App Server.

[image]